# How to pass arguments when execute jobs in parallel with a shared job queue using python schedule module

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I intended to run several jobs in parallel and followed the example [here](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/FAQ.rst) using a job queue, but it executed once and raised an exception `'NoneType' object is not callable` when I tried to pass arguments. The code listed below:

```
import Queue
import schedule
import threading
import time

def job(arg):
    print 'Argument is %s' % arg

def worker_main():
    while True:
        try:
            job_func = jobqueue.get()
            job_func()
        except Exception as e:
            print e

jobqueue = Queue.Queue()

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, job(1))
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, job(2))

worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_main)
worker_thread.start()

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        sys.exit()
```

The output is:

```
Arg is 1
Arg is 2
'NoneType' object is not callable
'NoneType' object is not callable
'NoneType' object is not callable
'NoneType' object is not callable
'NoneType' object is not callable
'NoneType' object is not callable
...
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for that is the parameter passed to `do` method in `schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, job(1))` is actually `None`.

Because the code is calling `job` function and passing 1 (and 2) as arguments to `job`. So the return value of the `job` function (which is `None` since it's just printing) is passed as the second argument to `do` method call. So instead of a function reference, a `None` instance is being stored in the job queue.

The problem of passing arguments to the jobs is that the `do` method from `schedule` package, can accept extra arguments for the job to run, but what is being scheduled, is to put the job in the queue, and the queue items are only function references without extra arguments.

One solution is to put the jobs alongside their arguments to the queue. Then the worker needs to get them and call the job by passing the arguments to it. Something like this:

```
import Queue
import schedule
import threading
import time

def job(arg):
    print 'Argument is %s' % arg

def worker_main():
    while True:
        try:
            job_func, job_args = jobqueue.get()
            job_func(*job_args)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

jobqueue = Queue.Queue()

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, (job, [1]))
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, (job, [2]))

worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_main)
worker_thread.start()

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        sys.exit()
```

Here we're putting a tuple of the job function reference, and a list of arguments to the queue.
Then the worker would fetch them, and passes the list of arguments to the job function.

Another solution is to wrap the jobs (`job(1)` and `job(2)` calls) in other functions that do not need an argument, then register those functions to the job queue, like this:

```
def job1():
    job(1)

def job2():
    job(2)

jobqueue = Queue.Queue()

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, job1)
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, job2)
```

Comment: This will raise a `job() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` exception, I think the argument was passed to `do` function, what I need is passed it to function `job`

Comment: True, I didn't notice the function being scheduled, is not the `job` but putting the job into the queue. I updated the answer.