# Scheduling Python script to run at a specific time

Tags: python

I have written a function that monitors the status of services at different servers. Here is the code:

```
def heathcheck(server_address, service_name):

try:
    shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=server_address,
                      username ='abc',
                      password ='xyz', missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept, connect_timeout=100)

    with shell:
        result = shell.run(['service', service_name, 'status'])
    print '%s on host : %s' % (result.output, server_address)
except spur.RunProcessError as e:
    print e.stderr_output
except IOError as e:
    print e.message
except Exception as e:
    print e.message
return '%s on host on thread : %s' % (result.output, server_address)
```

I want to run this script everyday at a specific time. I am using this small piece of code :

```
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(heathcheck('server_address', 'httpd'))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(10)
```

But i keep on geting this error even after I am following the correct example (https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/FAQ.rst):

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Any idea what the problem maybe ?
I am using https://github.com/dbader/schedule module

Comment: Can you run it via cron?

Comment: The problem is that you are calling the function and passing the result as the first argument. The first argument should be the function (which would make it callable), not the result. Take a look at the example again.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688596/how-to-pass-arguments-when-execute-jobs-in-parallel-with-a-shared-job-queue-usin

Comment: @pushkin Got your point. Runs perfectly now.

Comment: @kandarpgandhi Glad to help. Keep in mind that these threads will run only if your main process is running in the background. It *might* be a good idea to use a cronjob as Lostsoul suggested.

Comment: @pushkin I am new to this and this helps a lot. How should I make sure that it runs everyday even in my absence ? Should I add it to a CI pipeline ?

Comment: @kandarpgandhi I'm not sure about that, but if you look up cronjobs, you will find that you can specify exactly how often it should run.